# Java math equation solver [not normal equations]

Tags: java, algorithm, math, equation

I need a method in java which returns a solve for an equation this equation without code is like this :

1. get a number(Z)
2. and an angle(C) in *radians*

then find the value of X which is the solution for this equation:

```
a = Integer( z*cos(c) ) // temp must be integer
//now we have the value of a
// we put it in b
b = a
//now we look for the value of x that solves this equation
b =? Integer( X/cos(C) ) // X also must be integer
 X = ?? // we must get X the solves the equation above
```

Example: consider

```
Z = 15
C = 140 // full angles will be casted ..it will be rooted to ~-0.0629*PI

temp = Integer( 15*cos(140) // -2.96 )
temp <-- -2 //after parsing to integer
-2 = Integer ( X )/cos(140)

what is X ?
```

I tried to implement this method in java but most of the times it stuck finding a result
this code doesn't find a direct solution like i want it tests numbers till it  gets it but in many of times it can't find a result and keeps looping to the infinity . Also it is so slow in finding the result and i call that function more than 500,000 times in the program

```
int Rounding(int z, int c){
      int offset = 20 ;
      int x;
      int test = (int) ( z*Math.cos(c) - offset );
      int solution;
      while(true){
        solution = (int) ( test/Math.cos(c) );
        if(solution == z){
          x = solution;
          break;
        }else{
          test++;
        }
        /*
        if(solution > z){
          offset ++;
          solution = (int) ( z*Math.cos(c) - offset );
        }
        */
      }
      return x;
  }
/*Note : the function will return x only when it solves this : */
int returned_Z = (int) ( x/Math.cos(c) )
// returned_Z must be equal to z
```

After that that variable x will be stored in a file ...
then when the file opens this variable x will be returned to z with this function :

```
int returning(int x, int c){
  int z = (int) ( x/Math.cos(c) );
  return z;
}
```

Comment: fix your equation you write `temp = Integer( z*cos(c) ) temp = Integer( X/cos(C) )`

Comment: Odd definition of "equation". Did you mean `Integer( Z*cos(C) ) = Integer( X/cos(C) )`? Also does `Integer` round to the nearest or round down?

Comment: What do you see when you debug into it? Is it doing the right math inside your loop? Is it converging to a value or oscillating? Is there an integer solution? Debugging is an important step here...

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: no it is not giving errores i debug but in many times  it can't find an integer number that can solve the equation

Comment: @shudipta-sharma see the example you will understand

Comment: @meowgoesthedog see the example you will undertsand ...and no it doesn't round it just removes the floating point part no matter what it is

Comment: @ZOLDIK: removing the fractional part is "truncation", or "rounding down".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your posting, we have

```
temp = Integer( 15*cos(140) // -2.96 )
Find X such that
temp = Integer ( X/cos(140) )
```

We can solve this for X without the integer conversions.

```
X = 15 / cos^2(140)
```

or, in general

```
X = Z / cos^2(C)
```

This will give you an exact solution for X; you may apply the integer intermediate requirement if needed for some other purpose.

---

**Update per OP comment**

You have a defined mathematical relationships between `X`, `temp`, and `Z`.  Truncating the intermediate result breaks some of that relationship.  In short, if you restrict `X` to integers, you cannot guarantee that you get exactly `Z` when you apply the inverse operations.

In particular, you have a transcendental function `cos`; you cannot dictate that it will be the ratio of your integers `temp` and `X` or `X` and `Z`.  There do exist point solutions for `cos` that are known rational numbers, but very few.

If I misunderstand the problem -- I realize that we have some translation problem -- then please update your question to specify the correct problem.

Comment: sorry but that's doesn't help , x must be integer and as said down , when returning it it must give us back the number z

Comment: yes that's what i thought too ... restricting the result to integers might not make the equation possible in some cases ... So sadly ..i have to change how to encrypt that x value

Answer (score 0):

Actually the eqn has infinite number of solutions. Say `temp = 2`. And you write:

```
2 = Integer ( ( X )/cos(140) )
```

If we take `Integer()` for all real numbers in the range `2.0 <= num < 3.0`, it results in `2`. That's why infinite number of solutions possible. For example, if we take `2.5` from the range:

```
2 = Integer (2.5) is true
so we can write, 
    x / cos(140) = 2.5
 => x = 2.5 * cos(140)
      = −1.915111108
```

If we take another `2.3` from the range:

```
x = −1.761902219
```

Since there infinite number of real numbers in the range `2.0 <= num < 3.0`, the number of solutions is infinite too.

So you can't just expect a single solution for x. If you do, then use:

```
int Rounding(int z, int c){
    int test = ( z*Math.cos(c) );
    int x = (int) ( test*Math.cos(c) );

    return x;
}
```

This will give you a correct answer. But as I said before, there are infinite number of solutions for x.

Comment: Thanks but like that i can't guaranteed that if i took x and did : x/Math.cos(c)  it doesn't always be equal to z

Comment: i've added the purpos of this down

Comment: yes you are correct when it was  //  Integer ( ( X )/cos(140) )      // but i wronged writing it now it is fixed : Integer ( X ) / cos(140) . this question is solved that it is not possible , thank you for your time :)